# Problem creating a new route in Gohpish tool

Tags: go, gophish

To whomever familiar with this tool [Gophish](https://github.com/gophish/gophish), I'm trying to create a new route, to add a new feature.

The proccess to do so as i noticed from reading the code, u have to add a list item to `[nav.html][1]`:

```
<li>
     <a href="/newItem">newItem</a>
</li>
```

Then create your html page and put it in the [templates](https://github.com/gophish/gophish/tree/master/templates) folder
Then edit `[route.go][1]` file with the following:

- Edit `registerRoutes` function to add this line 
  `router.HandleFunc("/newItem", mid.Use(as.newItem, mid.RequireLogin))`
  then create `newItem` function

```
func (as *AdminServer) SmiShing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := newTemplateParams(r)
    params.Title = "NewItem"
    getTemplate(w, "newItem").ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", params)
}
```

And this should be it. But it seems like i'm missing something

Also when i try to delete one of the exciting routes in `router.HandleFunc` nothing changes and the route still exists when a run the tool.

So, does it have something to do with databases, or what is it that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the import package, it has some errors

make sure they are all working perfectly